# How do I point multiple domain name suffices to one suffix?

Tags: domain-name

I have two domain names pointing to the same site, identical names except for the suffix ('.com' and '.co.nz').

Somewhere I got the impression that it's preferable to make one point to the other, eg. no matter which suffix I type into the address bar, it always shows the '.com' version after I hit enter.

There was some ridiculously immemorable name for this process - and because I can't remember it I can't even search to find out why it's important I do this!

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Alex Karasulas

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are asking.. On the .co.nz domain is probably a redirection to the .com domain?

Comment: They both already point to the same website, but if you type in the '.co.nz' suffix, from then on all the pages you visit on the site will have '.co.nz' in the url, and if you type '.com' then all the urls will have '.com' ... meaning that some people will visit (for instance) "http://www.happytobevisuals.co.nz/about_us.php" and some will visit "http://www.happytobevisuals.com/about_us.php".

I think the main problem might be with analytics and SEO, that the visitor count is split between two url versions of exactly the same page? Not sure ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current approach and the .com and .co.nz domains having the same content is that search engines [generally handle](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) them as different websites, but punish them, because the have no unique content.

Google therefore [recommends using 301 redirects](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) to redirect from your second domain to your main domain, so they know they all belong to one website. Then they can e.g. summarize the number of links over the web to your website to generate one pagerank.